# How to launch a separate Firefox instance in Kiosk mode only with the default profile?

Tags: firefox, webapps

I'm searching for a way to launch a separate Firefox instance with my default Firefox profile in Kiosk mode (recently introduced in Firefox 71) only. This is needed for a web application.

This instance should be separate from my default Firefox instance, i.e. has its own title and icon, therefore behave like a separate application, analogues to Mozilla's discontinued [Prism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla_Prism) project.

After searching around, this should be doable by creating a `.desktop` file in `~/.local/share/applications/` with the following content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=MyWebApplication
Exec=firefox --kiosk --no-remote --class WebApp
StartupWMClass=WebApp
Icon=browser
Type=Application
Actions=new-window;new-private-window;
X-MultipleArgs=false
StartupNotify=true
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
Terminal=false

[Desktop Action new-window]
Name=Open a New Window
Exec=firefox -new-window

[Desktop Action new-private-window]
Name=Open a New Private Window
Exec=firefox -private-window
```

Having `--class` in `Exec` and `StartupWMClass` with the same name is crucial in order that this instance is recognized as an independent one, see [here](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-running.html) and [here](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html). The same goes for `--no-remote` for Firefox.

But if I launch this `.desktop` file, then I get:

> Firefox is already running, but is not responding. To open a new window, you must first close the existing Firefox process, or restart your system.

I assume that Firefox needs another profile for another instance, because with `Exec=firefox --kiosk --no-remote -P --class WebApp` I can create another profile and use it in this instance, but I want to use my default profile instead.

Is that even possible and has somebody already found a solution?

Comment: Would `firefox -P profile_name -no-remote` work?

Comment: `Exec=firefox --no-remote -P default --class WebApp` still doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Your use of `--no-remote` is incorrect. It should be `-no-remote`. Your use of `--class` may also be incorrect.

Comment: I've tried `-no-remote` and `--no-remote` – both are valid, but `--` is the recommended way, see `firefox --help`, but `--class` is the only proper notation. It's not the commands, it's the profile, because it works with another profile, but not the default one.

Comment: Then I don't know. Sorry.